# Polymorphic shape class draws whatever shape recently created?

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, polymorphism, shapes

I have classes Triangle and Circle which inherit from Shape, and a class Application which draws circles and triangles like so:

```
public class Application extends JPanel{

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    super.paintComponent(g);
    Shape[] shapes = new Shape[4];
    Circle circle1 = new Circle(100,100,80);
    Triangle tri1 = new Triangle(20,40,40);
    Circle circle2 = new Circle(300,300,100);
    Triangle tri2 = new Triangle(30,30,30);

    shapes[0] = circle1;
    shapes[1] = tri1;
    shapes[2] = circle2;
    shapes[3] = tri2;

    for(Shape shape : shapes){
        shape = (Shape) shape;
        shape.draw(g, this);
        }

    }
}
```

The code draw the circle with no error, but the triangle drawn is always the second one(`tri2`). I was playing around and realized that the triangle drawn will always the one that defined last. I was wondering why this could be the case?

Comment: If you don't show us your `Shape` class or your `Triangle` class, how could anyone possibly tell you what you've done wrong?  (Although my guess is that you've got some fields marked `static` that shouldn't be).

Comment: What do you mean with "the triangle drawn will always draw what is defined last"? E.g. could you provide some example output what you are seeing right now, and what you were expecting?

Comment: Sorry for lack of details you guys still getting used to asking questions on here..

Answer (score 0):

I had values x and y for each class that marked where to begin drawing each shape, these variables were statically defined for the super and sub-classes. This caused Triangle's x and y components to be defined with the most recent object's.